# Watching Netflix through a VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, vps, netflix

Recently I bought a VPS from DigitalOcean. I setup a PPTP VPN so I could watch us Netflix content from outside the US. Now that I have it setup and all my traffic is going through the VPN, Netflix is still showing my home country content. Pandora is working, and when I search my IP it shows im in NY, so I guess traffic is being routed correctly. I have also tried to delete flash settings and cookies from browser.

Any ideas on what could be happening?

Comment: Have you googled Hola Unblocker?

Comment: I tried using, it did not work. I know there are other alternatives, but I wanted to use the vps

Comment: Are you watching Netflix on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to choose the right VPN.  sometimes VPNs are mistaken from Proxies, which can work from some sites and not for others.  Try using other reputable VPN providers like vpnauthority.com. The PPTP VPN will allow you to watch Netflix, Hulu, Pandora, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely DNS servers that giving you away to Netflix. Make sure that when you're connected to VPN you use their provided DNS servers, or find some public one in the country you want to mimic.

Answer (score 0):

Netflix uses a cookie (when watching on your computer via a browser) to store your location.

To switch countries:

- close Netflix.com page
- open your brower's cookie page (Firefox: Preferences...|Privacy|Show Cookies...)
- delete all cookies that contain 'netflix.com'
- start VPN
- open Netflix.com

You might consider using a cookie-manager extension for your browser.  I use Self-Destructing Cookies for Firefox--it automatically deletes Netflix's cookies when I close the page (so I don't need to remove them manually).

This will, of course, force you to enter your credentials each time you visit Netflix.com.  Your browser should offer to remember your credentials; this would eliminate the need to enter them constantly.

This is a useful site: [FlixSearch](https://flixsearch.io/).